# Swapping X and Y on my touchscreen

Tags: android, touchscreen, beagleboard

I successfuly installed (after 1 week of work) Android on BeagleBoard C4. As display I use Lilliput 669 with an eGalax Usb TouchController. Everything seems ok with exception of touchscreen which have X and Y axes reverse.

> I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001
>   Version=0210 N: Name="eGalax Inc. USB
>   TouchController" P:
>   Phys=usb-ehci-omap.0-2.2/input0 S:
>   Sysfs=/devices/platform/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0/input/input1
>   U: Uniq= H: Handlers=event1  B: EV=9
>   B: ABS=600000 3
>
> I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001
>   Version=0210 N: Name="eGalax Inc. USB
>   TouchController" P:
>   Phys=usb-ehci-omap.0-2.2/input0 S:
>   Sysfs=/devices/platform/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0/input/input2
>   U: Uniq= H: Handlers=mouse0 event2  B:
>   EV=1b B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   B: ABS=600000 3 B: MSC=10

Do you know how to reverse X and Y axis for my touchscreen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this post is old, but this was a problem I encountered recently while I swapped the broken touchscreen from my Android tablet. The replacement was a poorly manufactured p.o.c.s... Anyway, after I plugged it in, the xy was swapped first, then I turned the connector over and it was just an x-axis problem. I knew that if I flipped the glass over, it would fix it, but that would make the connector too far away from the port on the motherboard. So I just plugged it in, and went to the settings of the tablet, and calibrated the touchscreen from the settings menu. Done.
That's it.
SOLUTION:
Just go to the settings option in the menu and find the "Touchscreen Calibration" option and calibrate it again. This should fix it :) Or just flip connector around and try again :)
The reason I posted this is to help others who might have this problem :)

Comment: wasn't so simple. I rewrite some parts of the EGalaxy driver to make it work. Anyway thanks for suggestion.